# Http Callout doesn't return the latest data

Tags: integration, httpresponse

Http callout is not returning the latest json response.

Below is the code used for calling Rest based web service. But it doesn't return the latest response. It takes time for the data to get updated. If we call the same service after 10 min the latest data is returned.

Prior to calling the get request we are calling Put request.

```
/*** Method to Get all Contracts from External system
public HttpResponse getHttpCall()
{
    System.debug(' ---------------- Inside getHttpCall --------------');
    Http httpProtocol=new Http();
    HttpRequest request=new HttpRequest();   
    String endpoint='http://orbservice.com/customers';
    request.setEndPoint(endpoint);
    request.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse response=new HttpResponse();
    response=httpProtocol.send(request);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't be a salesforce problem, does your endpoint work with a cache of some sorts ?

Comment: Http protocol are stateless so this behaviour cannot be expected from Apex.

Comment: We tried calling Rest service via Rest Client....it is working fine. Using the Rest client we are getting the updated data. But unfortunately not via Salesforce. Is it possible to set no cache in http callout header ?